# Sub directory not available as package on parent package despite having __init__.py file in every folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, import, python-import

If importing a package, it does not load its child packages, despite all folders having `__init__.py`.

The example:

```bash
mkdir -p parent/child
touch parent/__init__.py
touch parent/child/__init__.py
```

Looks like:

```bash
$ tree parent               
parent
├── child
│   ├── file.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── __init__.py
```

```bash
$ python3            
Python 3.11.0 (main, Oct 26 2022, 14:04:35) [GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import parent
>>> parent.child
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'parent' has no attribute 'child'
```

This works, but is annoying when you have a lot of subdirectories to explicitly import them all.

```bash
>>> from parent import child
```

Why doesn't this work? And how would I make all my subpackage easily available on the parent package?

Comment: "Why doesn't this work?" because you only imported `parent` and that module hasn't defined `child`, in `parent/__init__.py`, you can `import parent.child as child`. Then, you can do `import parent; print(parent.child)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga But I need to have that repeated for every subpackage I have in parent. Why won't Python subpackages on its own?

Answer (score -1):

Create **init**.py file like this it worked for me.

```
$ tree
├── __init__.py
├── main.py
└── parent
    ├── __init__.py
    └── child
        ├── __init__.py
        └── file.py
```